# O meu dispositivo não atualiza ao fazer uma modificação no código do ionic

Tags: mobile, ionic2

Estou com um problema, ao fazer uma alteração no código do aplicativo tipo colocar uma cor ou um título de alguma coisa, no meu dispositivo não atualiza, mas no browser sim, coloque um ola na home page e no meu celular não aparece essa nova linha inserida como faço para sincronizar, ao incluir ou editar algo no dispositivo alterar também ?

Answer (score 1):

ionic serve --lab só funciona no browser, para rodar no dispositivo sem ter que ficar compilando direto tem que usar o comando

```
ionic cordova run android --device --livereload
ionic cordova run ios --livereload # para iOS
ionic cordova emulate android --livereload #caso esteja usando o emulador
```

fonte: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/

Ou usa o IonicDevAPP
https://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-devapp/